# let $m \neq 0$ .Consider the line $y = mx + \frac{a}{m}$ and the parabola $y^2 = 4ax.$ choose the true statements.

Tags: geometry

let $m \neq 0$  .Consider the line $y = mx + \frac{a}{m}$
and the parabola $y^2 = 4ax.$

choose the  true statements.

$(a)$ The line intersects the parabola at exactly one point.

$(b)$ The line intersects the parabola at two points whenever $|m| < 2\sqrt a.$

$(c)$ The line is tangent to the parabola only when $|m| = 2\sqrt a$

i know that condition of tangency of $y = mx + c  $ to the parabola  $y^2 = 4ax $ is $c = a/m$

Any hints/solution

Comment: And that condition is met. So what is stumping you?

Comment: What are the roots of the quadratic equation in $x$ ?